# Button within mat-toolbar has wrong left/right position

Tags: angular-material

I have mat-toolbar and a button at the end of it.
When i try to get the position of the button it gives me wrong value of left/right.
In the following example both buttons return same positioning although one is at the beginning of the screen and the other is at the end.

Html:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
 <mat-toolbar-row>
    <span> toolbar</span>
    <span class="example-spacer"></span>
    <button #rowBtn mat-button (click)="clickButtonOut()">
      click me
    </button>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
<button #outOfRowBtn mat-stroked-button (click)="clickButtonOut()">button outside of toolbar</button>
```

Ts:

```
 @ViewChild('rowBtn',{static: false}) row: any;
 @ViewChild('outOfRowBtn',{static: false}) out: any;


 clickButtonRow(){
   alert(this.row._elementRef.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().left)
 }

clickButtonOut(){
  alert(this.out._elementRef.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().left)
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bk38qb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always call the same function. You can never get the right value. You have to change the one function call from `clickButtonOut()` to `clickButtonRow()`!

Your Code:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <span> toolbar</span>
    <span class="example-spacer"></span>
    <button #rowBtn mat-button (click)="clickButtonOut()">   <-- wrong function
      click me
    </button>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
<button #outOfRowBtn mat-stroked-button (click)="clickButtonOut()">    <-- right function
button outside of toolbar
</button>
```